# Generating CFG for C# code

Tags: c#, control-flow-graph

I am looking for a tool to draw [Control Flow Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) for C# code..

Something like [AVRORA](http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/avrora/cfg.html) but for C#

Any ideas?

Comment: There is some code visualisation capability in VS2012, but not necessarily what you want. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Understanding-complex-code-with-Code-Map-ENU

Comment: I know this is very old, but did you ever find a suitable tool for this?

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix sounds promising:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/phoenix/thread/7688b910-8291-436a-967c-6bc5cc71c898

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(compiler_framework)